# issue with merging NSManagedObjectContext with background thread changes

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have data that should be changed from background. 
There is a method that works in background and inits the new `NSManagedObjectContext`, makes changes and call save.
Then I got a `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` with right data in notification object. 
Next I call

```
[mainManagedObjectContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)
                                           withObject:notification 
                                        waitUntilDone:YES];
```

But in my `UITableViewController` nothing changed and I don't get in

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

or

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject 
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type 
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

When I'm making same changes to main context in main thread everything works fine. I've some successful experience with merging from background threads before but this situation drives me crazy and so I'm asking for help.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC a fetched results controller only gets an update notification if you save the main context after merging.